# OOP Method to stop a loop

Tags: python, loops, oop

I have a hypothetical class Human that has a method 'talk' in an infinite loop, how do I stop it during run-time?
P.S. I am working on an audio recording application (interview prep for NSA :P) and I want to stop the recording whenever I want without any external interrupt. How to set self.run to False or call stop_me when the while loop is running?

```
class Human(object):

    def __init__(self,run=True):
        self.run=run

    def stop_me(self):
        self.run=False

    def talk(self):
        while self.run:
            print('blabla')     

#main
person1=Human()
person1.talk()
```

Comment: just use `break` ! do you try `break` in `def talk(self):` ?

Comment: change self.run= True, than in while loop change it to , while self.run = True,  then with another function you can change the value of self.run and the while loop should stop

Comment: What do you mean by stop it during run-time. Do you mean, when the `talk` method is called (your code executed in the interpreter), it is an infinite loop unless you let it stop. What do you mean by ''whenever you want'?

Comment: I think you want to stop this when you press a key? Why don't take an input and check if the input received is 'X' stop it?

Comment: Obviously someone needs to call the `stop_me()` method for the loop to stop. Who should do that, while running an infinte loop? It seems you need another thread, to run and then pass a message from that one (i.e., call the `stop_me()` method).